# YASM assembly calling stdout.write in jitted function

Tags: c++, assembly, stdout, machine-code, yasm

I'm trying to write a just-in-time compiler and I have a piece of code that just doesn't want to work. My platform is x86-64 ubuntu.

I have the following code written in yasm:

```
bits 64

mov rdx, 1
mov rcx, 'A'
mov rbx, 1
mov rax, 4
int 0x80
ret
```

So if I understand correctly this should write `A` to stdout. Now I compile this code with

```
yasm -f bin test.yasm
```

This resulted in the following machine code:

```
0x48 0xc7 0xc2 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x48 0xc7 0xc1 0x41 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x48 0xc7 0xc3 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x48 0xc7 0xc0
0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xcd 0x80 0xc3
```

and then I read the resulting code in C++ and call it:

```
void *memory = allocate_executable_memory(sizeof(code));
emit_code_into_memory(sizeof(code), code, memory);
JittedFunc func = reinterpret_cast<JittedFunc>(memory);
func();
```

I think that the C++ part is fine since I've already tried it with simple arithmetic operations and it worked well.

So anyway there is no segmentation fault, the code seems to be executed but nothing happens, there's nothing in stdout.

Any advice?

**//EDIT:** full C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sys/mman.h>

void* allocate_executable_memory(size_t size) {
    void *ptr = mmap(
        0,
        size,
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS,
        -1,
        0
    );
    if (ptr == (void*)(-1)) {
        perror("mmap");
        return nullptr;
    }
    return ptr;
};

void emit_code_into_memory(size_t code_length, uint8_t *code, void *memory) {
    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(memory), code, code_length);
};

typedef void (*JittedFunc)();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    /* Use like this:
    bin/jit 0xb8 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xc3
    */
    if (argc <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    uint8_t code[argc-1];
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        code[i-1] = std::stoul(argv[i], nullptr, 16);
    }

    void *memory = allocate_executable_memory(sizeof(code));
    emit_code_into_memory(sizeof(code), code, memory);
    JittedFunc func = reinterpret_cast<JittedFunc>(memory);
    func();
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Not sure, but any chance it's buffered?

Comment: Also, is `int 0x80` supported in 64-bit?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think that `int 0x80` is supported: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux I've also tried `syscall` with the same result. I'm not sure what you mean by buffering? Isn't pure asm unbuffered?

Comment: Is there an in between stage that could possibly hold your output before sending it to stdout?

Comment: @simplicisveritatis I'm not sure, I'm really new to this stuff. :) I've added full C++ code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The write syscall expects a pointer to the thing to write, not an immediate. Also, 64 bit uses `syscall` instruction with a different calling convention. This is important for pointers which would otherwise be truncated to 32 bits. Furthermore, also the function numbers are different, so your code actually invokes the `stat` syscall as can be seen using `strace`:

```
stat(NULL, NULL) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
```

You should try the following code instead:

```
push 'A'
mov rdi, 1   ; stdout
mov rsi, rsp ; buf
mov rdx, 1   ; count
mov rax, 1   ; sys_write
syscall
pop rdi      ; cleanup
ret
```

This uses the stack to store the letter to print. The cleanup could use any caller-saved scratch register, or could be rewritten as `add rsp, 8`. The return value from the system call is in `eax`.

The 32 bit version could look like:

```
push ebx     ; callee-saved
push 'A'
mov ebx, 1   ; stdout
mov ecx, esp ; buf
mov edx, 1   ; count
mov eax, 4   ; sys_write
int 0x80
pop edi      ; cleanup buf
pop ebx      ; restore ebx
ret
```

Notice that `ebx` has to be preserved according to calling convention.

Comment: That works, superb! How could we do that using `int 0x80` on a 32-bit machine?

Comment: so instead of passing an immediate value, you are pushing it on the stack and then passing the stack pointer, right ?

Comment: And is there a particular reason why you pop to `rdi` for cleanup?

Comment: @freakish because the stack is the caller's responsibility here.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Yeah, I know why he pops but why to `rdi`?

Comment: Hester might comment but in context I think it's an arbitrary choice.

Comment: Yes, `rdi` is an arbitrary scratch register. Could have used any caller- saved register according to the calling convention. I deliberately avoided `rax` though, because that has the return value. `add rsp, 8` would have worked too.